# How to handle "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of undefined" on a getJSON call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an HTML that invoke a REST webservice and get the JSON answer.
When I enter a wrong parameter I can catch the error without problem but sometimes some results on the JSON are null. How can I catch that situation?

My HTML:

```
<div id="divname"></div>
```

My javascript:

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
             $('#divname').html(data.result[0].dest[0].pred[0].time);
     })
.done(function() { alert('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); $('#divname').html('Wrong Parameter.'); })
.always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
```

A good JSON result would be like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "string01": "104",
        "string02": "104 - blablabla",
        "string03": "104",
        "string04": "blobloblo",
        "string05": "blablabla",
        "dest": [{
            "pred": [{
                "time": 1461348846,
                "sec": 102,
                "min": 1,
                "string11": "514-String",
                "string12": "Some String",
                "string13": "Some other String",
                "number": 0
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

But sometimes, when there is no data to show, I get something like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "string01": "104",
        "string02": "104 - blablabla",
        "string03": "104",
        "string04": "blobloblo",
        "string05": "blablabla",
        "dest": [{"pred":[]}]
    }]
}
```

I get the following in chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'time' of undefined
```

I understand why this is failing but I don't know how to catch this error to show on the HTML that is failing.

Comment: Just check to see if the parent property is there before you try to set properties on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check for pred's length:

```js
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
   if (data.result[0].dest[0].pred.length) {
       $('#divname').html(data.result[0].dest[0].pred[0].time);
   } else {
       // handle the case with empty pred here
   }
     })
.done(function() { alert('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); $('#divname').html('Wrong Parameter.'); })
.always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
```

Alternatively, check if pred[0] is undefined:

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
   if (typeof data.result[0].dest[0].pred[0] !== 'undefined') {
       $('#divname').html(data.result[0].dest[0].pred[0].time);
   } else {
       // handle the case with empty pred here
   }
     })
.done(function() { alert('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); $('#divname').html('Wrong Parameter.'); })
.always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
```

Comment: Glad to help - let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Hey @TAGraves How can I catch the error response? In this case textStatus = "error" and errorThrown = "Bad Request" when I enter a bad paramenter but from the URL I get "Param BLABLA not a valid integer". How can I catch that error?

Comment: Is the webservice throwing that error in valid JSON, or not? I.e. is the response at the URL `{"error": "Param ... integer"}` or is it just `Param ... integer`?

Comment: Just the text.. not valid JSON

Comment: Is it available in `jqXHR.responseText`?